# How to install my network adapters driver? TP Link TF3200

Tags: internet, ethernet, adapter

I am not able to access internet in Linux and i thought i might give updating adapters' driver a go .But I dont even know where to start. Any help?

```
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
```

lspci -nnk | grep 0200 -A3

```
05:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Sundance Technology Inc / IC Plus Corp IC Plus IP100A Integrated 10/100 Ethernet MAC + PHY [13f0:0200] (rev 31)
    Subsystem: Sundance Technology Inc / IC Plus Corp IC Plus IP100A Integrated 10/100 Ethernet MAC + PHY [13f0:0201]
    Kernel driver in use: sundance
    Kernel modules: sundance


[    2.912433] sundance 0000:05:00.0: enabling device (0100 -> 0103)
[    3.245192] sundance 0000:05:00.0 enp5s0: renamed from eth0
[   38.118459] enp5s0: Link up
[   38.119125] enp5s0: Link changed:


[    0.146727] pci 0000:05:00.0: [13f0:0200] type 00 class 0x020000
[    0.146752] pci 0000:05:00.0: reg 0x10: [io  0xd000-0xd07f]
[    0.146763] pci 0000:05:00.0: reg 0x14: [mem 0xf7110000-0xf71101ff]
[    0.146817] pci 0000:05:00.0: reg 0x30: [mem 0xf7100000-0xf710ffff pref]
[    0.146878] pci 0000:05:00.0: supports D1 D2
[    0.146879] pci 0000:05:00.0: PME# supported from D1 D2 D3hot D3cold
[    0.432170] pci 0000:05:00.0: Adding to iommu group 7
[    2.885357] sundance 0000:05:00.0: enabling device (0100 -> 0103)

ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN 
group default qlen 1000
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 ::1/128 scope host
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136293/discussion-on-question-by-furkan-torun-how-to-install-my-network-adapters-driver).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In our chat, we learned that, reproducibly, if you booted without working ethernet, it could be restored with:

```
sudo modprobe -r sundance && sleep 3 && sudo modprobe sundance
```

I recommend that you ask a new question here to get assistance to create a start-up script:

```
sleep 3 && modprobe -r sundance && sleep 3 && modprobe sundance
```

Please note that 'sudo' is not possible and therefore not required in a script that runs silently during boot.